# How to make responsive design like Instagram in React Native?

Tags: react-native

When opening Instagram on the iPad, it displays like this.

[image: Instagram]

Instagram

It looks like Instagram doesn't use `react-native-responsive-screen` because the size of each screen is the same as in iPhone.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for people to help you, you should add a description of what you have already tried and code snippets if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Any iPhone only app has an iPhone size on iPad.

iOS apps can be:

- iPhone only,
- iPad only,
- universal (for both iPhones & iPads).

It can be configured in Xcode.

These settings are not related to React Native. It's an iOS specific thing.